# Domain of integral of complex function from 0 to 1

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

If we have $t\in[0,1]\mapsto h(t)\in\mathbb{C}$ a continuous function and $H(z)=\int_0^1 \dfrac{h(t)}{t-z} dt$, is $\mathbb{C}\setminus[0,1]$ the domain of $H(z)$?

I was using the fact that continuous functions are integrable, and the product of continuous functions is continuous. But couldn't $H(z)$ still be well-defined on $[0,1]$ since there is only one point of discontinuity?  I have no idea how to show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $[0,1]$ is a compact set any point $z$ outside this set has positive distance from it: $z \notin [0,1]$ implied there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|z-t| \geq \delta$ for all $t \in [0,1]$. Hence $H(z)$ is well defined. In fact it is continuous on $\mathbb C \setminus [0,1]$.

Comment: Can you explain further please?

Comment: If $|z-t| \geq \delta $ for all $t \in [0,1]$ then $|\frac {h(t)} {z-t}| \leq \frac 1 {\delta} |h(t)|$ and hence $\int_0^{1} |\frac {h(t)} {z-t}| \, dt <\infty$.